# Slider Not Pausing On Mouseover - jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider, onmouseover

I have a slider that needs to pause when you hover your mouse over it. It works when you hover your mouse over it **AND** keep moving your mouse. When the mouse is over it and is stationary, the slider starts again. I want it to keep paused even when the mouse is stationary. Here is the code:

```
$('slider').observe('mouseover', function(e) {
    my_glider.stop();
});
function startGlider1() {
    my_glider.start();
}
$('slider').observe('mouseout', function(e) {
    if (typeof(timeout) != "undefined") {
        clearTimeout(timeout);                              
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(startGlider1, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I changed 'mouseover' to 'mouseenter' and 'mouseout' to 'mouseleave' and now it works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try hover() function of jquery.

```
function startGlider1() {
    my_glider.start();
}
$('slider').hover(function() {
    my_glider.stop();
}, function() {
    if (typeof(timeout) != "undefined") {
        clearTimeout(timeout);                              
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(startGlider1, 4000);
});
```